# Authentication for git push over http

Tags: git, apache-2.2

I've set up apache to use git-http-backend as per the instructions in the pro git book, and its manpage.
My apache config now looks like:

`SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git

SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">

        AuthType Basic

        AuthName "Git Access"

        Require group committers

</LocationMatch>`

I can clone a repo using `git clone http: //user@url/git/repo.git`
which prompts me for the password for 'user', then continues.
However, when I attempt to push, I'm prompted for my password twice, and then get an error:

`Cannot access URL http: //user@url/git/repo.git/, return code 22`

(I've inserted a space into the URLs, because the spam prevention mechanism won't let me post otherwise)

When I look at my apache log, I see:
`192.168.1.151 - - [12/Sep/2010:20:11:22 +0100] "GET /git/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "git/1.7.2.3"

192.168.1.151 - - [12/Sep/2010:20:11:23 +0100] "GET /git/repo.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 59 "-" "git/1.7.2.3"

192.168.1.151 - - [12/Sep/2010:20:11:23 +0100] "GET /git/repo.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/1.7.2.3"

192.168.1.151 - - [12/Sep/2010:20:11:26 +0100] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/ HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "git/1.7.2.3"`

I've added 'user' to the 'committers' group on the server (seemed easiest to just follow the instructions), and my local .netrc (chmodded 600) looks like this:

`machine address

    login user

    password pass`

Every instruction I've found seems slightly unclear as to whether I have to enable DAV for the dir in question (I thought that was the old way to do it, though).
I *could* just use gitolite, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this first…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROPFIND is a non-standard webdav HTTP method.
You'll need to enable webdav for the location of your repository.
Enable mod_dav in httpd.conf and add this to your vhost LocationMatch block:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
  #...
  Dav on
</LocationMatch>
```

Then make sure your Apache user has write access to your repository.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing in your apache log is the following line:

```
  192.168.1.151 - - [12/Sep/2010:20:11:22 +0100] "GET /git/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "git/1.7.2.3"
```

git-http-backend is returning a 403/Forbidden code when the client asks to use the git-receive-pack method. It then falls back to WebDAV, but *using WebDAV is **not** necessary*.

I had the same problem; in my case this was due to REMOTE_USER not being set. In my case, REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER /was/ set, so I set REMOTE_USER to REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER, which solved the problem.

I documented my setup on my [blog](http://blog.procrastination.nl/2010/10/git-http-backend-on-shared-hosting-with.html) - and see if that works for you.

Comment: @valhallasw Where did you add the REMOTE_USER part?

Comment: In the CGI handler script - before calling git-http-backend, it sets REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER if $REMOTE_USER is not set.